# Inf of a mutivariate function

Tags: real-analysis, tag-removed, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $f(x_1,\ldots , x_n) = \frac{x_1}{x_2+x_3} + \frac{x_2}{x_3+x_4} + \cdots + \frac{x_n}{x_1+x_2}$, defined for $x_i>0$.

1. Is there $(x_1, \ldots ,x_n)\in {\mathbb{R}^*_+}^n$ such that $f(x_1,\ldots , x_n) < n/2$?
2. Can we find $\inf_{x_i>0}f(x_1,\ldots , x_n)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is discussed briefly as a generalization of Shapiro's cyclic sum
inequality by J. Michael Steele in his book
[The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7Fm3r9jcbqYC&lpg=PP1&dq=Steele%2520Cauchy&pg=PA104#v=onepage&q=Shapiro%27s&f=false).
He remarks that (1.) holds for $n\ge25$ and refers to this paper:
P. J. Bushell, Shapiro’s “Cyclic Sums", 
*Bull. L.M.S.* (1994) **26**, 564–574.

Answer (score 3):

This is discussed in detail on the following MathWorld article: [Shapiro's Cyclic Sum Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ShapirosCyclicSumConstant.html)
.
Detailed proofs of the main result (inequality holds only for even $n \le 12$ and odd $n \le 23$) can be found in the following [note](http://olympiads.mccme.ru/lktg/2010/5/5-1en.pdf) by Khrabrov.